# ANDROID TabLayout with small icons

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to use tabLayout using only icons -

```
     tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_undo_black_48dp));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_redo_black_48dp));
```

but the problem is the tab bar that i get shows small icons with a lot of space around it and if I use a linearLayout on imageViews it shows the right size.
[image]

The above one is of tabLayout and the bottom is the Linear Layout and both are using same drawables. How do i fix this in TabLayout?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

          <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_redo_black_48dp"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_undo_black_48dp"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

or your can add your custom layout to TabItem by

> android:layout

for more detail :[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and [TabItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabItem.html)

Comment: How to set the image if I use custom layout for  TabItem?

Comment: you need to create seperate layout with Imageview and add it by "android:layout= @include/YOURLAYOUT"